# find unique elements in matrix based on a subset of columns

Tags: r, matrix, duplicates

I have a table which i want to transform

```
     t LabelA LabelB start stop
 [1,]  1      4      9     1    2
 [2,]  1      3      5     1    2
 [3,]  1      1      6     1    2
 [4,]  2      4      9     1    2
 [5,]  2      3      5     1    2
 [6,]  2      1      6     1    2
 [7,]  2      7      2     2    2
 [8,]  3      3      5     3    4
 [9,]  3      1      6     3    4
[10,]  3      7      2     3    5
[11,]  3      4      9     3    5
```

I want to filter the data in a way that rows which just differ by there number in the first column are removed (not completely but only the duplicate). So for rows 1 and 4 only row 1 should remain in the table. Or for row 3 and 9 only row 9 should remain. It is important that the information in the first column is remained and that the earliest occurance of the row remaisn in the table not the other incidences.

Comment: Can you specify your desired output

Answer (score 1):

You can use `duplicated`:

```
mat[!duplicated(as.data.frame(mat[, -1])), ]

      t LabelA LabelB start stop
[1,]  1      4      9     1    2
[2,]  1      3      5     1    2
[3,]  1      1      6     1    2
[7,]  2      7      2     2    2
[8,]  3      3      5     3    4
[9,]  3      1      6     3    4
[10,] 3      7      2     3    5
[11,] 3      4      9     3    5
```

where `mat` is the name of your matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Try using duplicated function:

```
mymx <- matrix(c(1,4,9,1,2 ,1,3,5,1,2 ,1,1,6,1,2 ,2,4,9,1,2 ,2,3,5,1,2 ,2,1,6,1,2 ,2,7,2,2,2 ,3,3,5,3,4 ,3,1,6,3,4 ,3,7,2,3,5 ,3,4,9,3,5), ncol=5, byrow=T)
mymx[!duplicated(mymx[,-1]),]

> mymx[!duplicated(mymx[,-1]),]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    4    9    1    2
[2,]    1    3    5    1    2
[3,]    1    1    6    1    2
[4,]    2    7    2    2    2
[5,]    3    3    5    3    4
[6,]    3    1    6    3    4
[7,]    3    7    2    3    5
[8,]    3    4    9    3    5
```